# Rotate image in javascript an SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Like in the picture, How can I rotate the pictures from a single picture ? But according to the templates I choose...

[image]

Comment: Please post what you have done till now. It will be helpful to go through.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this from https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-rotate-images-using-JavaScript?share=1 :

```
var id = 'obscene-stuff';//The ID of the <img> element you want to rotate
var deg = 90;//The rotation angle, in degrees
document.getElementById(id).style = 'transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
```